# C++ project crashes after glewinit()

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, cmake, glfw

(Im using Clion and Cmake on Macosx Intel chip)

I wan't to make a Window Application with GLEW. But i get this error:

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

I heard that you should define "GLEW_STATIC" in the preprocessing. But I have no idea how Clion works

My main.cpp:

```cpp
#include "GL/glew.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;
    glewInit();
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

and my cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(renderer)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
include_directories(/usr/local/Cellar/glfw/3.3.8/include)
include_directories(/usr/local/Cellar/glew/2.2.0_1/include)

add_definitions(-DGLEW_STATIC)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -framework CoreFoundation -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT ")
add_executable(renderer main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(renderer /usr/local/Cellar/glfw/3.3.8/lib/libglfw.3.3.dylib)
target_link_libraries(renderer /usr/local/Cellar/glew/2.2.0_1/lib/libGLEW.2.2.dylib)
```

How do i fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glewInit()` requires a [current OpenGL context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) to operate correctly.  As written in your code `glewInit()` will fail and leave its `glClear()` function-pointer set to `nullptr`.

Call `glewInit()` after `glfwMakeContextCurrent()` ['returns'](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/intro_guide.html#error_handling) `GLFW_NO_ERROR` and [verify that it returns `GLEW_OK`](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html).